# Visual Studio Code is not showing the output of Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am really new to Python and just started the course "Python 3 basics by Sendtex (Link: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCfzlCWGWYyIQ0aLC5w48gBQ)".

- I am trying to use Python with Visual Studio Code.
- The downloaded version of Python is 3.6.4.
- I have installed the Python extension in Visual Studio Code and have followed the procedure.

However, I am not able to get any output. Below is the attached screenshot.

[image]

If I select Python it enters debugging mode. So, there isn't any output.

Comment: and what happens if you switch to the "OUTPUT" tab at the bottom ?

Comment: Save this file, then go to the Terminal tab at the bottom and type `python hello.py` and press Enter. This should run the code and show an Output.

Comment: @Guillaume Output Tab shows nothing. As you can see in the screenshot when I press run then a popup comes that too is shown in screenshot.

Comment: @user8212173 it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

## Using the Python Extension Run/Debug commands

#### Notes

1. I recommend reviewing the [official Visual Studio Code Python documentation and tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python). That provides several of the basics, with running and debugging the "official" way.
2. There are multiple ways to configure built-in launches:

   - When running or debugging Python in VS Code, there are a few options that you can change in your "launch.json" file. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49572658/vs-code-starts-debugging-in-integrated-terminal-instead-of-debug-console/70990689#70990689) for more details.

### Run or Debug with the built-in Python extension commands

You can run or debug using the "triangle" icon and dropdown in the upper right of your editor window, when the editor window is focused on a python script file (i.e. typically a file named *.py).

[image]

You may need to setup a run/debug configuration to use this (see below), or it may automatically step you through creating one.

The output will normally go to a new "Python" terminal in the "terminal" window (Ctrl-`, to open it). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49572658/vs-code-starts-debugging-in-integrated-terminal-instead-of-debug-console/70990689#70990689) for how to change that behavior.

---

### Setting up a run/debug configuration

##### Easy option:

- Use the menu item **`Run/Add Configuration`, and follow the prompts at the top of the VS Code window.
- Some of the additional details are shown below.

##### More involved option:

- Click the run/debug icon on the left vertical icon toolbar.

  - [image]
- The window says "RUN AND DEBUG" at the top, with a drop-down that shows "No Configurations" for a given folder or workspace until you set this up.
- The gear to the right of the dropdown will have a red dot if you need to configure this:

[image]

Updated Image (1/2022) - Changed from just 'Debug' to 'Run and Debug':
[image]

- Click the gear icon (or in the menu, use **Run/Open Configurations**), and in the middle at the top, Visual Studio Code will open a window titled "Select a debug configuration".

  - The available options will depend on exactly how you have Visual Studio Code setup and configured
  - There should at least be a "Python File" option with the Python extension installed. Select it.

[image]

Now your debug configuration box on the top left of the debug pane should say "Python: Current File":

[image]

Visual Studio Code will add a file to your current workspace or working folder called `.vscode/launch.json`, and opened it for edit.

Answer (score 3):

### Simplest Answer: Run the file directly in a terminal

1. Open a terminal in VS Code (**View/Terminal** in menu or Ctrl-`, which is the "Ctrl" key and the "Grave" or "Tick-mark" key, normally at the top left of keyboard above tab).

   - This will open the terminal to the root of the folder VS Code has open (the one that shows up in the Explorer sidebar - Ctrl-Shift-E to see).
2. Run the python script in the current directory with a simple **`python my_script.py`** command.

   - If the script is in another directory than the root of the current workspace or folder you opened the terminal in, you will need to change to that directory (using `cd` commands, etc.), or add the absolute or relative folder path to the name of the script.
3. The output will show up in the same terminal.

#### Notes

- You must have a python executable on your path, be in an active virtual environment, or give the full path to the python executable.
- Your `python` command may be `python2` or `python3` on some installs (usually linux), and can be just `py` for the Python Launcher (auto-installs with typical Python for Windows installs).
- This option will not use any 'launch.json' configurations, and cannot be easily used to debug with.
- You can configure the default terminal that is used, such as Git Bash, CMD, or Powershell (on Windows). You can also open additional terminal windows of any configured type using the "+" icon and it's dropdown, in the terminal window.

Answer (score 2):

During installation if you forget to tick in check box for `path` and then if you are running any python file on visual studio it will not return any `output` untill and unless you have not added it into `visual studio code`.

First of all go to `File` → `Preference` → `Settings.json`

```
    "code-runner.executorMap":
{
  "python": "\"C:\\Program Files\\Python39\\python.exe\""
```

I have attached the screenshot for your better understanding!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found this post when trying to find how to show my python code output in the VSCode output window instead of the integrated terminal window. In my case the problem was caused by a Code-runner setting. Here's how I fixed my problem :

- Open Command Palette(`CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `P`).
- Search and select `Preferences : Open Settings (UI)`.
- Search the following setting : `Code Runner : Run in Terminal`.
  [image: Code Runner setting in VScode IDE]
- **Untick** the box.

Now when you select `Run Code` (or `CTRL` + `ALT` + `N`) option when running your code, the Output window should work.

[image: Run code option on vscode]

[image: Working VScode output window]

### Note

- The integrated terminal will not show code output now.
- The output window in VScode is `read-only`. My method is not suitable if you are taking input from user.

Answer (score 0):

After writing your code, press ctrl+s in vscode to save it. then you can run your code and the result will be displayed. My problem solved this way.

I hope it helps you too

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76984829/11107541

Comment: I think this answer is a try and error. Issue is probably due to settings and won't be just due to "saving of code" Therefore, some supporting information is required to support this answer

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, but figured that close to top right of your Visual Studio Code there is a little green triangle saying "running code in Terminal".
I you wanted to see some kind of print('Hello') it is does the job.

Comment: The fact that such a simple and essential task as _viewing output from a script_ involves this much ink being spilled is an indication that VScode is an overhyped product.

Answer (score -2):

I ended up scrapping code and moving my project to Visual Studio 19. Works just fine now. Prints show up in a command prompt.