# Having problems with debugging in .vscode

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-3.6, vscode-debugger

I've had a big problem with debugging in VSCODE lately. I have tried to fix it my self by searching the site and reinstalling some of my extensions.

Instead of showing my results in the **debug console** it writes the following output to my **terminal**:

```
cd /Users/AVFL/Documents/Programming ; env "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8"
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" /usr/local/bin/python3
/Users/AVFL/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.3.1/pythonFiles/PythonTools/visualstudio_py_launcher.py
/Users/AVFL/Documents/Programming 54323 34806ad9-833a-4524-8cd6-18ca4aa74f14 RedirectOutput,RedirectOutput
/Users/AVFL/Documents/Programming/Python/Projects/Entrepeneuring/employeeDatabase.py
```

and the results from my script show up below that. The results also show up in the debug console but I would like them to only show up there.

I am debugging with the **Python: Current file**. I have tried changing the **console to `none`** in the external and integrated terminal function, but I need those to be default.

What can I do to make it debug in the debug console when I use **Python: Current File**?

---

I've seen one post with this question but they changed the console to none and debug in the Python: Integrated Terminal instead of Current File

The problem occurred when I made a virtualenv in my folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VScode starts debugging in integrated terminal instead of debug console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49572658/vscode-starts-debugging-in-integrated-terminal-instead-of-debug-console)

Comment: I've tried to do as the answer in the one you link but it still outputs in both debug console and terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer myself. Instead of changing the other configurations to print the info in the debug console I create a new Configuration with the name "Python: Current File" which I added as the fist configuration. I made the console "none" in this configuration and I deleted the other one. This solved my problem with out removing other vulnerable settings.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to your launch.json script and find thre attach part. Change the setting from integrated terminal to none. Should work :)

Comment: I've tried to do so but it just outputs in both terminal and debug console

Comment: That sounds very strange have you remembered to save the launch.json file?

Comment: yeah that was it. I found another solution tho so I can keep the integrated terminal function. I created a new configuration

Answer (score 0):

Setting `"console": "None"` in the `launch.json` is not valid in the latest versions of VS Code. Note, however, that you will still get the desired behavior, but VS Code will consider it an invalid setting. To make VS Code happy, set `"console"` to `"internalConsole"` to get the output to go to the **Debug Console** instead of to a **Terminal**, like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "internalConsole"
        }
    ]
}
```