# Issue while using Python in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python

I am getting the following error message while using Python with Visual Studio Code:

> R:\python>cd r:\python && cmd /C "set "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8" && set "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" && "C:/Program Files (x86)/Python36-32/python.exe" C:\Users\smit097.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2018.7.1\pythonFiles\PythonTools\visualstudio_py_launcher.py r:\python 50144 34806ad9-833a-4524-8cd6-18ca4aa74f14 RedirectOutput,RedirectOutput r:\python\testhelloworld.py "
>
> 'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

After some time there is a pop up asking me to open launch.json.

This message pops up only when I debug and run a new code. The old code runs fine without error.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling VSC but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Open the the Debugging Configurations `launch.json` by going to

**Debug -> Open Configurations**

In `launch.json`, change the

`"console": "IntegratedTerminal"` to `"console": "none"`

I had the same problem and the above fix worked for me. You could also try adding

```
"debugOptions": [
    "RedirectOutput"
]
```

to see if it works for you.

Source:

[Having problems with debugging in .vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49639072/having-problems-with-debugging-in-vscode)

[VScode starts debugging in integrated terminal instead of debug console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49572658/vscode-starts-debugging-in-integrated-terminal-instead-of-debug-console)