# Debug Console does not open automatically

Tags: visual-studio-code

So recently vscode was updated to start debugging through the terminal instead of the debug console. The fix to that as stated in this answer: [VS Code starts debugging in integrated terminal instead of debug console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49572658/vscode-starts-debugging-in-integrated-terminal-instead-of-debug-console?noredirect=1&lq=1) is the `"console": "none"` option needs to be set for every single launch configuration apparently but doing so does not make the bottom panel popup when starting debugging.

Is there a way to fix this?