# VS Code Terminal Java Hide Path

Tags: visual-studio-code

When the output is displayed in the Terminal, how can I hide all that unnecessary information with the path from showing every time? All I want to see is just my program data.

```sh
sh-3.2$ /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.5.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp "/Users/Alex/Documents/My Java Project/bin" app.MyClass 

Enter username
test
Username is: test
sh-3.2$
```

Answer (score 3):

First go in preferences-> settings and search for (Java › Debug › Settings: Console) Change its setting from default to (internalconsole) and that's it.

you will get a terminal path free output on debug console

Answer (score 0):

I was in a situation just like this solutin is

```
 "console": "internalConsole"
```

paste this to `launch.json` 
if you want detailed detailed answer click this[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49572658/vs-code-starts-debugging-in-integrated-terminal-instead-of-debug-console)

Answer (score 0):

This will work, but you'll run into an error message when using a Scanner object. The best solution I've found so far is to create two configurations in the settings.json file. I have...

```
{
    "type": "java",
    "name": "In Debugger",
    "request": "launch",
    "mainClass": "${file}",
    "console": "internalConsole"
}
```

...when I want to run it in the debugger console and have a cleaner output, and...

```
{
    "type": "java",
    "name": "Int Terminal",
    "request": "launch",
    "mainClass": "${file}",
    "console": "integratedTerminal"
}
```

...when I need to run it into the terminal.

Though this video shows how to set it up for Python, it works pretty much the same for Java: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NSZqn1VrzVc&ab_channel=ReynaldAdolphe

Answer (score 0):

Install Code Runner Extension **-->** Click on the settings icon on the Code runner extension  **-->** select Extension settings  **-->** Scroll and check for **Code-runner: Show Execution Message** uncheck it and the reload the Vs Code

Now run any language code java or python, long Path won't be available, Only **Output is displayed**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Debugger for Java extension is installed.
Then go to VS Code **Preferences** > **Extensions** > **Debugger for Java**
Change from the drop-down menu from the default `integratedConsole` to `internalConsole`

Answer (score 0):

Just Enable 'code-runner:Run In Terminal'