# Java output in VScode

Tags: java, visual-studio

I have just started to use Java in VScode and when i run the code i see a path in blue color which i dont want to see.

```
PS C:\Users\Kamil\Desktop\java>  c:; cd 'c:\Users\Kamil\Desktop\java'; & 'c:\Users\Kamil\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-debug-0.29.0\scripts\launcher.bat' 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\bin\java.exe' '--enable-preview' '-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages' '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' '-cp' 'C:\Users\Kamil\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\62ccb9798b03c2ab99f215c8f0933a8d\redhat.java\jdt_ws\java_9392f169\bin' 'Sa' 
Hi Java
```

Could you please tell me how to hide theese information. I just want to see the output of the code in the terminal. Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: Clear the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979383/java-clear-the-console)

Comment: This is not what i am asking. I just want to see only the output of the code, not the path in the terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add the bin folder under the folder where you installed Java (for example C: \ Program Files \ Java \ jdk1.6.0_17 \ bin) to the Path variable of your system.

Comment: I have already added bin to the path environment :(

Comment: Oh okey. Someone who has the same situation as you asked, I hope the answers here will be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59368671/vs-code-terminal-java-hide-path