# How can ı hide python path in visual studio code?

Tags: python

[image: How can ı hide or short this paths,ı cant stand it like this]

Even hiding the yellow path would be enough.

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59368671/vs-code-terminal-java-hide-path

Comment: What for ? To screenshot it ?

Comment: That wont work arseniy,no when ı use terminal not screenshot