# When I run my python code in VS code it displays the output in the Terminal tab and not the Output tab

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-3.8, python-extensions

Currently using `VS Code version 1.43.`2 and `Python 3.8.1`. I want to know how will I make my codes display in the Output section and NOT the Terminal section when I ran them

Comment: change your setting to `run code in terminal` to `false`

Comment: I think this is related: [VS Code starts debugging in integrated terminal instead of debug console](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49573055/2546289)