# How do I change terminal display? Visual Code on Mac

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, display

When Running my code I really only want to display the code I'm working on. I don't want to display what seems to be the folder address. Is there a way to not display that?

I mean when im running my code. I want to see the answer to my code only so to just display

28

.... not the folder name desktop/cpp etc etc

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hit `Ctrl + B` to hide that. To Hide the terminal ``"Ctrl + `"``

Comment: press on `X` button

Comment: Its not the menu on the left im trying to remove its the address in my compiled code....

Comment: Is this what you want? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62345409/vs-code-shows-print-output-in-terminal-instead-of-output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed you were having some trouble with VS-Code.

[Here's](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) a good list of commands which can complete your task.

I noticed you stated that you were on a Mac as well, so more than likely the CTRL + option won't be necessary; try the " ⌘ + " instead!

- To remove / hide the folder explorer window, simply hit "*⌘ + b"*
- To remove / hide the terminal as well, try using *"⌘ + `"*

Edit:

I noticed you were also having some issues with the output of your code. The *"addresses"* to your output are symbols that ( usually ) address incorrect operations.

Try doing something like this when writing out your function:

```
printf( "i%\n" ); // <- Adding a newline to the operation deducts the symbol.
```

I hope this helps-

Comment: Thats amazing thank you, I'm on week one of learning so finding it all very overwhelming