# How can i have a clean terminal in vs code?

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm new to vs code and still learning about the software. i like vs code but the terminal keeps bugging me. Every time i run a code it shows the execution path and massages. i just want to see the codes result i mean a clean terminal. i haven't found any solution online. Any help will be much appreciated.
i have already tried checking the settings and tweaking the terminal settings but can't find the option. i want to keep the previously run code result so that's not an issue.

[image]

Comment: If you don't want to see your program's output perhaps you don't need the terminal but something else like a task. What do you need the command for?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62345409/vs-code-shows-print-output-in-terminal-instead-of-output/62350835#62350835

Comment: @Álvaro González i want to only see my codes output in the terminal. don't wanna see other things like path etc. i know about the launch.json changing option but it doesn't work for me. it says "console" isn't allowed. maybe it's because i'm coding in  c++. i don't know. if you know any other way it would be useful for me. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that the text shown in your picture has been created by Visual Studio Code and if you run that same command in a regular PowerShell prompt you see something entirely different? That sounds really strange and, indeed, it cannot be diagnosed with just that cropped picture. Can you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62433105/edit) the question and show the full command and output in both integrated and external PowerShell? You don't need the hassle of uploading pictures, text will do just fine.