# VSCode issues when running a C file and displaying output

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run C programs/files from VSCode. I've followed a guide to setting up the gcc for VSCode to use, and it "mostly" works. However, when I run a file, it only outputs to the debug console, which is rather messy. I would prefer if it only output to the "output" window. [image]

If I click on the output window and then try to run the file, I get this error. [image]

This is what my tasks.json file looks like, where I've tried to change build from `cppbuild` to `shell`, as well as removing the "file" lines that I saw recommended on other threads, which didn't solve my issue. [image]

Also notice how in the drop down menu for my panel, I don't have a "Code" option that I see in other people's VSCode [image]

TLDR: I want VSCode to display the output of a C file into the Output window, not the debug console. I also want to understand why I am given the "Cannot build and debug because the active file is not a C or C++ source file" error. MinGW has been downloaded and GCC has been set up properly, AFAIK.

Comment: You can likely find the solution you are looking for here [VS code shows print output in TERMINAL instead of OUTPUT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62345409/3422102)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed "Code Runner" extension?

Comment: Whoops I totally forgot that! Thank you this fixed it