# How to get RTL (right-to-left) text working in VS Code integrated terminal?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, right-to-left, hebrew

If I print in the DEBUG CONSOLE it's fine, every where else VS code display Hebrew just fine, just when the script print to the TERMINAL the Hebrew is upside down, why?
[image]

**Update:** it works fine when debugging on external terminal

[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug in the IDE. I don't know what we're supposed to be able to do about it. The right place to talk about it is MSDN, I would imagine.

Comment: is it "upside down"? Or is it backwards? It looks backwards to me from a cursory glance

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I think it would be GitHub, actually, where development and bug reports of Visual Studio Code takes place (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode). By the way, MSDN was renamed to Microsoft Docs back in 2016. It now goes by Microsoft Docs or Microsoft Learn (as the site subdomain changed ~1 year ago from docs.microsoft.com to learn.microsoft.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Solution (or a work around) I found:***

In .vscode/launch.json:

`"console": "internalConsole"`
save and reload the VScode window, and start debugging again.

Source: [VS Code starts debugging in integrated terminal instead of debug console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49572658/vs-code-starts-debugging-in-integrated-terminal-instead-of-debug-console)

This redirects the output to DEBUG CONSOLE instead of TERMINAL.  DEBUG CONSOLE doesn't seem to have this problem.

[image: Screenshot 2023-04-12 at 1 33 09]

Another option I haven't tried. It might be good if you don't have the Python VScode plugin:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/9696

Comment: input("Enter input") stopped working. So "console": "externalTerminal" might be an option

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with the VS Code integrated terminal since at least VS Code 1.13.0. See [Terminal doesn't support RTL languages #28571](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/28571). The regression in that version had to do with new optimizations and features that assume everything is on a grid that only contains half or full-width characters ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/28571#issuecomment-308195479)). That issue ticket is closed to be tracked upstream in the xtermjs repo: [Support RTL languages #701](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/issues/701). <sup><sub>You can show your support for the issue ticket by giving a thumbs up reaction to the issue. But please *don't* make a "me too" comment. "me too" comments generally come off as annoying to repo maintainers because they clutter up discussion and don't contribute anything of significant value.</sub></sup>

For your reference / learning purposes, I found those issue tickets by googling "`github vscode issues intgrated terminal right to left text`".