# Right Align vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to Right Align vscode terminal

It completely messes up the texts and I have to do it in English, for example

It's really annoying when I want to work on projects with non-English languages

Comment: if you can provide me , with a picture so i can know where is the problem .

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75985838/how-to-get-rtl-right-to-left-text-working-in-vs-code-integrated-terminal