Message gets displayed as '?' in VS code
VS code does not displays my messages in Tamil, Russian etc. other languages, How can I make it to support all the languages I wish to display?
Suppose I want to display
Press 2 for Hindi. How can I do it in Hindi language in VS code. All it shows in the output is this.enter image description here
enter image description here
Expected this as output:
हिंदी के लिए 2 दबाएँ
but all i got was "?????????"


check this link: Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.; 2) this problem was asked before on this site (example How to correctly display unicode characters in VS Code's Integrated Terminal?)


Does this answer your question? How to correctly display unicode characters in VS Code's Integrated Terminal?

if not a duplicate of the one robert suggested, maybe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/75985838/11107541 (which I think would be the problem after fixing any codepage issues). I also want to make sure we're reproducing the same thing you're doing right: what do you see when you run echo 'हिंदी के लिए 2 दबाएँ' in the terminal? (how are you printing those messages? programming language runtimes and compiler source interpretation config are things too)

Does your external terminal display properly? Does it appear garbled in vscode only?

This is a matter of what font you're using for the terminal - it's not necessarily the same as the one used in the editor. You can set it through "terminal.integrated.fontFamily" in your settings.json. Once you choose a font that supports those character sets and restart the integrated terminal, you'll have them properly displayed.

I question this, though I did suspect possible font issue involvement. I don't think this would explain all the (what appear to be) basic question mark characters. there is a single replacement character though
