# Does anyone know why my Python script does not do anything while using openpyxl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

```py
import openpyxl as op

wb = op.load_workbook('socal.xlsx')

print(wb.sheetnames)
```

---

And this is the output when I run the script:

PS C:\Users\kielk\Desktop> & C:/Users/kielk/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe c:/Users/kielk/Desktop/atb.py

---

I am using Visual Studio Code on Windows 10. All it does is run the script and then nothing happens. It never prints the worksheet names when I run this script. Does anyone know why this is? The file 'socal.xlsx' is in the same location as the script is.

Comment: can i see the screen snap of vscode? want to see how you are executing this in the terminal. code is okay, so most likely the way it's been executed.

Comment: Check out this previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49529153/visual-studio-code-is-not-showing-the-ouput-of-python