# my python codes on vs code doesn't work on output only on terminal. I have tried to upgrade and downgrade the code runner extension but same

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

1. List item
   the output is shown on terminal rather than output panel

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are looking to the wrong output tab:
If you are referring to [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner), when using the run command (either through using the run button, shortcut, or command-palette), it redirects output to output tab "Code".

[image: Run button at top right corner of vscode window]

Maybe try switching to this tab.

[image: Code Runner Output]

---

You may also try to set the following setting in your *settings.json*:

```json
"code-runner.runInTerminal": false,
```

---

If this does not work, you might want to consider looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49529153/visual-studio-code-is-not-showing-the-ouput-of-python#answer-58704612), which seems to be a related question.