# How do I output simple code in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been using freecodecamp and I just want to have a place I can test things and save code. I been googling for a while and it seems so complicated I wonder why they don't just have a simple button or tab perhaps this is not something experienced coders want. Perhaps I should use a more beginner friendly app?

So far the best thing I have found is this:
[Visual Studio Code is not showing the ouput of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49529153/visual-studio-code-is-not-showing-the-ouput-of-python)

I am learning JS btw.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If it's purely JavaScript, you could run it with Node through the console tab in VSC.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I installed node JS. When I go to the terminal in VS code and type in node -v or node int it says the term node is not recognized. I would attach pics but I don't see an option in this comment reply box. Btw when I type node -v in command prompt it comes up showing my version.