# run python script in VS code works with run python file button, but not F5 key

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I can run a python script by pressing the run python file button:

[image]

but unable to run the same when pressing the F5 key or run from the dropdown menu.

[image]

I can also run in the interactive window fine:
[image]

And likewise i can run a notebook fine.

other checks:

I can verify that it doesn't debug by adding a breakpoint and running.

Would there be a key-binding that is missing perhaps ?
What is causing this and how can one fix the issue please ?

Comment: What happens when you hit F5? My VSCode brings up a menu to let me choose an interpreter to use, then after I select it it runs the program in debug mode. Are you sure the F5 shortcut is configured in your VSCode?

Comment: it looks like it is running (somewhere), but there is no output in the terminal or debug console. I dont get any option to select an interpreter.

Comment: what do you mean it looks like it is running somewhere? is it just running in debug mode? where do you see it running? you probably don't get an option to select an interpreter because it is already configured for your current project.

Comment: when code is executed i see the stop / step-over / step-into / play box appear for a second, but then it goes...  i can confirm that it does not execute the code (i checked this with `time.sleep(20)`.

Comment: could be a problem with your interpreter, do `ctrl` + `shift` + `p` and type `Python: Select Interpreter` and ensure it's set to the correct path

Comment: also, try the suggestions in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49529153/visual-studio-code-is-not-showing-the-ouput-of-python

Comment: Yes,  if i do `ctrl` + `shift` + `p` and select `run python file in terminal`,  this works...  it is nearly like the `f5` button is, for some reason not working.

Comment: Yeah, I don't really know what to tell you, you can try asking on the their GitHub vscode-discussion section: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-discussions/discussions

Comment: if you do `keyboard shortcuts` and search for `run` do you see anything linked to `f5` ?

Comment: Yes. F5 is bound to `Debug: Start Debugging`

Comment: same,  in the `when` column it says `debuggersAvailable && debugState == 'inactive'`   ... do you see that also ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246284/discussion-between-crock-and-d-l).

Comment: I want to know which operation mode you choose from the run drop-down menu? Are all the image examples mentioned in the debug mode? Is there an error or no response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the error is a bug in the Python extension.

If you go to the Extensions tab, select the Python extension, then click on the little arrow next to Uninstall > Install Another Version... and install 2021.12.1559732655 the debugger should work again.

Here is the link to the fix:   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/724858/vscode-debugger-not-working-for-python.html

In the meantime disable automatic updates to make it stick until they fix that.

To do this going to `settings`, typing `python.terminal.activateEnvironment` into the search bar and deactivating the checkbox.