# get vscode debug running from a specific python.exe path

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I try to get VS code debug (`F5` key) to run from the same place as the `Run Python File`.

The run code path is here:

```
c:/Users/Username/.Tactical/Local/envs/lon/python.exe
```

What i have tired so far (quite a bit from a previous question):
[run python script in VS code works with run python file button, but not F5 key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72914993/run-python-script-in-vs-code-works-with-run-python-file-button-but-not-f5-key/72935963#72935963)

I now wish to make the `launch.json` point explicitly to the same path.

The launch.json configuration looks like this:

```
{
"name": "Python: Base Console", // i am tesing this.
"type": "python",
"request": "launch",
"program": "${file}",  // can the user change this line to the correct python.exe ?
"console": "integratedTerminal"
}
```

I tried to change the `${file}` to the path, but this failed. Have I understood this correctly or what should I do to point to the correct `python.exe` ?

Answer (score 1):

The `"program"` configuration in `launch.json` is the entry module of the program.

If you want to specify the python interpreter for debugging, use the `"python"` configuration.

*A simple example:*

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".venv",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "python": "C:\\WorkSpace\\PyTest0628\\.venv\\Scripts\\python.exe"
        },
        {
            "name": "anaconda",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "C:\\WorkSpace\\PyTest0628\\Test6.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "python": "C:\\Users\\Admin\\anaconda3\\python.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can choose which configuration to use in the debug window:

[image]

*More configuration information about `launch.json`:* https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_set-configuration-options

Comment: I was looking for this answer. Unfortunately it does not work. Nevertheless I have voted this up as it provides clarity.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't help you. But can you tell me how it doesn't work?

Comment: Yes,  the answer good and eliminated a potential issue, but was not working because of another (specific VScode) bug which is correctly resolved here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72914993/run-python-script-in-vs-code-works-with-run-python-file-button-but-not-f5-key.  Hope that feedback is useful to everyone too.